# Connection with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, kotlin, ktor

I'm creating kotlin server-side application with MSSQL database. Connection with db works fine but I cant make any of DSL.

```
interface Department : Entity<Department> {
    companion object : Entity.Factory<Department>()
    val id: Int
    var name: String
    var location: String
}
object Departments : Table<Department>("t_department") {
    val id = int("id").primaryKey().bindTo { it.id }
    val name = varchar("name").bindTo { it.name }
    val location = varchar("location").bindTo { it.location }
}

val Database.departments get() = this.sequenceOf(Departments)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Database.connectGlobally(
        url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instanceName=HomeLibrary;user=myuser;password=mypassword",
    )
    Database.global.useConnection { conn ->
        for (row in Departments.select()) {
            println(row[Departments.name])
        }
    }
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, module = Application::module).apply { start(wait = true) }
}
```

Here is error list after starting the application. (I tried to call select after and before creating table with name t_department in database. Result was the same.)

```
2020-08-23 01:31:34.127 [main] INFO  me.liuwj.ktorm.database - Connected to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\HomeLibrary:1433; ......
2020-08-23 01:31:34.813 [main] DEBUG me.liuwj.ktorm.database - SQL: select * from t_department 
2020-08-23 01:31:34.813 [main] DEBUG me.liuwj.ktorm.database - Parameters: []
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 't_department'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:602)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7375)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3200)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:446)
    at me.liuwj.ktorm.database.Database.executeQuery(Database.kt:305)
    at me.liuwj.ktorm.dsl.Query$rowSet$2.invoke(Query.kt:91)
    at me.liuwj.ktorm.dsl.Query$rowSet$2.invoke(Query.kt:71)
    at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
    at me.liuwj.ktorm.dsl.Query.getRowSet(Query.kt)
    at me.liuwj.ktorm.dsl.Query.iterator(Query.kt:131)
    at com.homelibrary.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:38)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You don't specify an initial catalog in your connection string. i.e.: `t_department` probably doesn't exist in whatever database is configured as myuser's default database.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you for response. I added databaseName=HomeLibrary to jdbc and it works now.

Comment: @sqlvxd Can you please write the solution as an answer and accept it? That way users can find correct answers quickly